# Twodimensional ArrayList keeps adding new values

Tags: java, performance, arraylist

I have discovered the following behaviour with twodimensional ArrayLists in Java:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Date>> parentList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Date>>();
ArrayList<Date> childList = new ArrayList<Date>();

//Adding a date to childList
childList.add(date1);

//Adding a 'row' to parentList
parentList.add(childList);

//Adding another date to childList
childList.add(date2);

//Adding another row to parentList
parentList.add(childList);

System.out.println(parentList.get(0));
System.out.println(parentList.get(1));

//Expected output:   
//   [date1]
//   [date1, date2]

//Real output:   
//   [date1, date2]
//   [date1, date2]
```

So it seems that, eventhough the childList has been added to the parentList, newly added items to the childList also immediatly get added to the parentList.

I came up with the following solution for this problem:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Date>> parentList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Date>>();
ArrayList<Date> childList = new ArrayList<Date>();
ArrayList<Date> cacheList = new ArrayList<Date>();

//Adding a date to childList
childList.add(date1);

//Adding a 'row' to parentList
parentList.add(childList);

//Saving all current dates in cacheList
cacheList = childList;
childList = new ArrayList<Date>();

for (int i = 0; i < cacheList.size(); i++)
{
    childList.add(cacheList.get(i));
}

cacheList = new ArrayList<Date>();

//Adding another date to childList
childList.add(date2);

//Adding another row to parentList
parentList.add(childList);

System.out.println(parentList.get(0));
System.out.println(parentList.get(1));

//Expected output:   
//   [date1]
//   [date1, date2]

//Real output:   
//   [date1]
//   [date1, date2]
```

But I find this solution a bit redundant and ugly.

So I was wondering: is there a more elegant solution for this problem?

**EDIT**: Note that I need the `childList` to be cumulative. So it should contain all elements but everytime one more gets added to it and then it get's stored in the `parentList`.

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parentList.size(); i++)
{
     System.out.println(parentList.get(i));
}
```

Should output something like:

```
[date1]
[date1, date2]
[date1, date2, date3]
[date1, date2, date3, date4]
etc.
```

Comment: @RohitJain: No, because the list must be cumulative. So I need the first elements as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the same `childList` instance twice. All operations are done on that object. Since you added it twice, everything gives the impression of happening twice. To fix that, add a copy of the childList, like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Date>> parentList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Date>>();
ArrayList<Date> childList = new ArrayList<Date>();

//Adding a date to childList
childList.add(date1);

//Adding a 'row' to parentList
parentList.add(new ArrayList<Date>(childList)); // COPY!

//Adding another date to childList
childList.add(date2);

//Adding another row to parentList
parentList.add(new ArrayList<Date>(childList)); // COPY!

System.out.println(parentList.get(0));
System.out.println(parentList.get(1));
```